# Inject JavaScript using PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to load external webpage using PHP and to inject some JavaScript to it before displaying it.

To be honest, I have no idea at all how to do it (if it is possible). Somebody?

Example:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
// inject javascript here
echo $html;
```

Comment: I would like to inject some JavaScript before displaying it? So like a XSS attack?

Answer (score 3):

you need to simply construct the string of your js code if it is for that page only and add it inside a script tag and `echo` the entire string. like this:

```
echo "<script>alert('hi');</script>"; //as page script example
```

Or if it is a file include then include it properly with script tag and `echo` it and it will be available on your page. like this:

```
echo "<script src='path to file'></script>";
```

In that case your code structure will become like this

```
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    echo "<script src='path to file'></script>"; 
   // echo "<script>alert('hi');</script>"; //as page script example
    echo $html;
```

Comment: Please explain your answer as it has been flagged as low quality.

Comment: @RohitGupta where exactly can we see these flags.

Comment: I don't know how to find it again.  But I was reviewing the Low Quality Queue when I came across it.  And I was giving you a heads up, rather than recommending deletion.

Answer (score 1):

simply echo it

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
echo "your  javascript here"; 
echo $html;
```